# How do I complete my animation so that I may add nodes in composting?

Tags: node-editor

I'm a beginner who's been following [an online tutorial to learn how to use Blender](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U).

Currently I am trying to add the node "denoise animation", however the following error keeps appearing: "frame 'C:\TMP\001.png' not found, animation must be complete". Why does this happen?

[image: a screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Hi. When does this error appear? What action are you doing in Blender to get the error to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem, here's how it worked out: 
I guess you're pressing f3 when he says 'search' for the denoiser, and then denoise animation pops up, right?

[image: screenshot to show his problem]

You need to hit shift+a, then click on 'search' in the menu that pops up.

[image: the solution]

You should find an option simply called 'denoise', not 'denoise animation'
[image: the menu shows denoise]

Hope this helps!